# How can I assign my input's value to my array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, input

User would type the number of team they want and that number of inputs would show on screen to be typed from user. I had done that. But I want to assign my input's value to my array's element like $teams[$i]=$_GET['team'.$i.''] in for loop. That way, i can see the elements of my array which entered by user. I tried to assign them in my code with for loop. But i cannot see the result that i want. There are any syntax errors but i belive, i did logical mistake. Can anyone help with that? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
        <form method="get" name="teamNumber" style="margin:auto;">
        <label>Competition Name:&nbsp;
                <input type="textbox" name="competitionName"/></br></br>
            </label>
            <label>How many teams you want to add:&nbsp;
                <input type="textbox" name="teamnumber"/></br></br>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Create Teams!"/></br></br>
        </form>

<?php

    $competitionName=$_GET['competitionName'];
    $teamnumber=$_GET['teamnumber'];
    $submit=$_GET['sub'];
    $draw=$_GET['draw'];
    $teams=array();



            if(isset($submit))
            {
                if ( $teamnumber==1||$teamnumber==3||$teamnumber==5||$teamnumber==6||$teamnumber==7||$teamnumber==9||$teamnumber==11||$teamnumber==13||$teamnumber==14||
                     $teamnumber==15||$teamnumber==17||$teamnumber==18||$teamnumber==19||$teamnumber==20||$teamnumber==21||$teamnumber==22||
                     $teamnumber==23||$teamnumber==24||$teamnumber==25||$teamnumber==26||$teamnumber==27||$teamnumber==28||$teamnumber==29||
                     $teamnumber==30||$teamnumber==31  /* && $teamnumber>32 */ ) 
                    {
                        echo '<p>'.'You typed invalid team number'.'</p>' ; 
                    }

                    else{       
                            echo '<form method="get" name="addTeam">';

                            for($i=1;$i<=$teamnumber;$i++)
                            {
                                echo '<label> <input type="textbox" name="team'.$i.'" value=" Team'.$i.'"/> </label> <br> <br>' ;
                            }


                        switch($teamnumber)
                        {
                        case $teamnumber==2:
                            echo '<label> <input type="submit" value="Draw Final Round" name="draw"> </label>'. '</form>';
                            break;
                        case $teamnumber>3 && $teamnumber<=4:
                            echo '<label> <input type="submit" value="Draw Semi-Finals Round" name="draw"> </label>'. '</form>';
                            break;
                        case $teamnumber>4 && $teamnumber<=8:   
                            echo '<label> <input type="submit" value="Draw Quarter-Finals Round" name="draw"> </label>'. '</form>';
                            break;
                        case $teamnumber>8 && $teamnumber<=16:  
                            echo '<label> <input type="submit" value="Draw 16 Round" name="draw"> </label>'. '</form>';
                            break;
                        case $teamnumber>16 && $teamnumber<=32: 
                            echo '<label> <input type="submit" value="Draw 32 Round" name="draw"> </label>'. '</form>';
                            break;
                        }


                         }//end of else

                }// end of if

                if(isset($draw))
                {
                    echo '<p>'.$competitionName.'</p>' ;

                    for($j=1;$j<=$teamnumber;$j++)
                    {
                        $teams[$j]=$_GET['team'.$j.'']; 
                        echo '<p> Team'.$j.':'.$teams[$j].'</p>' ;
                    }


                }


 ?>
```

Comment: why don't you make our if like this `if( in_array($teamnumber, array(1,3,5)))` etc.

Comment: $teamnumber is not array element. That variable is only for getting value of my input's value. My array element must be the value of the input in for loop. That is not my answer but thanks anyway.

Comment: I know `$teamnumber` isn't an array. You can check if the value of `$teamnumber` is in the array of numbers. This makes your if statement way easier to maintain and read

Comment: I got your point. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing GET value to a variable directly without checking if it's set. this will cause an error.

try something like this.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['sub'] ) ) {
   if( !isset( $_GET['competitionName'] ) || !isset( $_GET['competitionName'] ) ) {
     echo 'Your Error Message';
    }
    else {
      $competitionName=$_GET['competitionName'];
      $teamnumber=$_GET['teamnumber'];
      $submit=$_GET['sub'];
      //$draw=$_GET['draw'];
      $teams=array();

      if( $teamnumber % 2 == 0 ) {
        //Code to be executed. switch statement and form in your case. 
      }
      else {
       //warn user when input value is odd. 1,3,5,7 etc 
       echo '<p>'.'You typed invalid team number'.'</p>' ;
      }
    }
  // Code  to be executed here. in your case for loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you for shortened my code, man. That looks much better way then before. But this is not my answer.

Comment: My code fecths the data and that works because i can see the entered data on my address bar. But I still cannot see the data on my display which is awkward :(